# Replacing tokens in a text file with replaced text

Tags: c++, parsing

This code parses a text file, replacing special tokens marked as $(token) with some replaced text.  The $ symbol can be escaped by entering a double $$.  In the example a user enters a text file containing tokens to replace and a separate mapping file with, for instance, colour:red to denote how to replace a token.

Some remarks I have is that is is not using any OO really.  Does it need to be?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

static void readToken(std::istream& strm, std::vector<char>& token)
{
   while(strm) {
      int c (strm.get());
      token.push_back(c);
      if(')' == c) break;
   }
}

static void lookup_replacement(const std::map<std::string,std::string>& token_map, 
                               const std::vector<char>& key, std::vector<char>& value) {
    if(key.size() > 3) {  //3 chars min are '$', '(' and ')'                      
        std::map<std::string,std::string>::const_iterator it = token_map.find(std::string(key.begin()+2, key.end()-1));
        if(it != token_map.end())
           value.insert(value.end(), it->second.begin(), it->second.end());
    }
}

static bool readTo(std::istream& strm, std::vector<char>& buf, const char term[])
{
   bool ret(false);
   while(strm) {
      int c (strm.peek());
      if(strchr(term, c)) {
         strm.get();
         int c2(strm.peek());
         if(c != c2) {
           strm.unget();
           ret = true;
           break;
         }
      }
      strm.get();
      buf.push_back(c);
   }
   return ret;
}

static void create_mapping(std::ifstream& strm, std::map<std::string,std::string>& tokens) {
   if(strm.good()) {
      std::string line;
      while(std::getline(strm, line)) {
         std::string::size_type pos = line.find_first_of(':');
         if(pos != std::string::npos)
            tokens.insert(std::make_pair<std::string, std::string>(line.substr(0, pos), line.substr(pos+1)));
      }
   } 
}

int main() {
   std::map<std::string,std::string> token_map;

   typedef std::map<std::string,std::string>::iterator map_iter;

   std::cout << "Enter path to text file to replace\nTokens to be replaced should be of form: $(token)\n";
   std::string file;
   std::cin >> file;

   std::cout << "Enter path to file with target token <-> replacement token in format:\n" 
                "<toreplace1>:<replacement1>\n<toreplace2>:<replacement2>\netc\n";
   std::string mapfile;
   std::cin >> mapfile;

   std::ifstream strmmap(mapfile.c_str());
   create_mapping(strmmap, token_map);

   // replaced text
   std::vector<char> replaced;

   std::ifstream strm(file.c_str());
   if(!strm.bad()) {
      while(!strm.eof()) {
         if(readTo(strm, replaced, "$")) {
            std::vector<char> token;
            readToken(strm, token);
            std::vector<char> replace_tok;
            lookup_replacement(token_map, token, replace_tok);
            if(!replace_tok.empty())
                replaced.insert(replaced.end(), replace_tok.begin(), replace_tok.end());
         }
      }
   }

   //print out replaced text
   std::cout << "your replaced text file\n";
   std::vector<char>::iterator pit = replaced.begin();
   while(pit != replaced.end())
      std::cout << *pit++;

   return 0;
}
```

The example input file I was using:

> Once upon a $(place1) there was a $(adjective1) $(colour) $(animal).
>
> Do you have a $$
>
> You have enemies? Good. That means you've stood up for something,
>   sometime in your life. by $(author) on $(date)
>
> A fanatic is one who can't change his mind and won't change the
>   subject. By $(author)

And the mapping file:

> ```
> place1:time 
> adjective1:cunning 
> colour:brown 
> animal:fox 
> author:Winston Churchill 
> date:06/06/2013
> ```

Comment: Why are you using vector<char> instead of string for the token etc?

Comment: So what happens with `$X`? You replacement thing is `$(<X>)`. So the questions are: 1) What is `$()` 2) what is `$<Y>` (Y => any character not '('). 3) What happens when the replacement is not terminated `$(<Z>\n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a little heavy on the code side.

Your definition of a token still leaves possibilities that you have not defined.

```
$$          :  Replace with $                                         Fine
$(<X>)      :  Replace with the mapped `<X>`                          Fine.

$(<stuff>\n : No closing ')'                                          Error
$()         : What happens with no identifier.                        Error
$<X>        : Some other character after '$' that is not '(' or '$'   Error
```

Especially your stream handling.
Its usually bad practice to test for `.good()`, `.bad()` or `.eof()` during normal processing. You want to test these after things go wrong to generate the appropriate error message or not. Usually stream code looks like this:

```
while(std::getline(stream, line))
{
    // correctly read a line
}

// or

while(stream >> value >> value2 >> value3 >> etc)
{
    // correctly read a value from the stream
}
```

You can use OO to compartmentalize your mapping.
Personally I would combine your `mapper` and `mapped` class into a single class.

```
class Mapper
{
    // Class contains a map from tokens => value
    // used via replace() to replace all tokens $(<X>) in string
    // with the values contained in the map.

    std::map<std::string, std::string>  replaceMap;
    public:
        Mapper(std::string const& fileName)
        {
            // Read all the mapping values from the file.

            std::ifstream   mapFile(fileName.c_str());
            std::string     line;

            while(std::getline(mapFile, line))
            {
                // Each line in the file contains a token/value mapping
                std::stringstream   linestream(line);

                std::string         token;
                std::string         value;

                std::getline(linestream, token, ':');
                std::getline(linestream, value);

                // Save the token and value
                replaceMap[token]  = value;
            }
        }

        std::string replace(std::string const& line)
        {
            std::string result;
            std::size_t last = 0;

            // Search for the '$' char repeatedly.
            for(std::size_t find = line.find('$');find != std::string::npos;last=find, find=line.find('$', find))
            {
                // Copy the inert text from line
                // into the result
                result  += line.substr(last, (find-last));

                // If the next character is a '(' then search for the closing ')'
                //
                // If we don't find a token `$(<X>)` then ignore the '$' and treat
                // it like a normal character. Note If <X> has no mapping then
                // we replace it with the empty string. Note if <X> is empty it is
                // is still value.

                bool hit = false 
                if ((find + 1 < line.size()) && line[find + 1] == '(')
                {
                    std::size_t end = line.find(')', find);
                    if (end != std::string::npos)
                    {
                        std::string key = line.substr(find+2, end-find-2);
                        result += replaceMap[key];
                        find = end + 1;
                        hit  = true;
                    }
                }

                if (!hit)
                {
                    // Token was not found.
                    // Put the '$' on the output and move on.
                    result  += '$';
                    find++;
                }
            }
            // Add the rest of the inert string to the output
            result  += line.substr(last);

            return result;
        }
};
```

This makes it easy to use:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Mapper  mapper(argv[1]);

    std::ifstream   input(argv[2]);
    std::string     line;
    while(std::getline(input, line))
    {
        std::string result = mapper.replace(line);
        std::cout << result << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks pretty good as it is. No project strictly "needs" OOP, especially one of this size. But here is one way to frame it in OOP -

Create a `Mapped` class and a `Mapper` class, both accepting stream references in their constructors. Perhaps constructor overloads accepting filenames. `Mapped.Map` could accept a `Mapper` instance reference, and use it to do the string replacement. When both objects are destroyed, both streams are closed.